# Angular ngIf firebase authentication directive makes DOM unresponsive

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angular-ng-if

I am using Angular's `*ngIf` directive to check if a user is currently logged in. Depending on the authentication status of the user(I'm using Firebase authentication), either the log in button or the user menu should show. Here's the code:

**.html**

```
<div class="right-side">
    <!-- Header Widget -->
    <div class="header-widget">

    <!-- User Menu -->
    <div class="user-menu" *ngIf="afAuth.authState | async as user; else showLogin">
        <div class="user-name"><span><img src="assets/images/agent-03.jpg" alt=""></span>Hi, {{ ... }}!</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a routerLink="my/profile"><i class="sl sl-icon-user"></i> My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="my/bookmarks"><i class="sl sl-icon-star"></i> Bookmarks</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="my/properties"><i class="sl sl-icon-docs"></i> My Properties</a></li>
            <li (click)="logOut()"><a routerLink="/"><i class="sl sl-icon-power"></i> Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <ng-template #showLogin>
        <a routerLink="/login-register" class="sign-in"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Log In / Register</a>
    </ng-template>

    <a routerLink="/submit-property" class="button border">Submit Property</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Header Widget / End -->
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
// ...
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }
```

When clicked, the user menu should pop up and display the list of links. However, it is unresponsive upon clicking.[This is the template I'm using](https://themeforest.net/item/findeo-real-estate-html-template/18936684). Here's the `.css` code for the menu's ul:

**.css**

```
.user-menu ul {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    right: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 190px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transform: translate3d(0,15px,0);
    padding: 16px 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.25s;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 110;
}
```

If I replace the code in the `*ngIf` directive like so `<div class="user-menu" *ngIf="1==1; else showLogin">`, the DOM is responsive:

But when I monitor a user's authentication state `*ngIf="afAuth.authState | async as user; else showLogin"`, it stays unresponsive.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Try changing constructor to:
user: Observable<any>;
 constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
this.user = afAuth.authState;
  }

and then keep on html as, 
*ngIf="user | async; else showLogin"

Comment: The code looks ok. Are you sure there is nothing wrong with the firebase setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the class

```
user$: Observable<firebase.user>;
    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth){
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState
    }
```

Inside the HTML write

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user; else showLogin">
```